Issue with CORS failing but request succeeding
I've set up CORS in the request pipeline in an ASP.NET Core Web Api/ReactJS SPA.  Reading the logs I see that the CORS policy is set up correctly but none of the requests are actually failing.  For example, where's the log output for one post request where I'm using an origin that's not specified in AllowedOrigins:
2024-09-23 21:23:42.7074||INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService|CORS policy execution failed. 
2024-09-23 21:23:42.7074||INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService|Request origin https://localhost:44498 does not have permission to access the resource. 
2024-09-23 21:23:42.7074||INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware|Executing endpoint 'TweetController.PostTweet (releaseplanb)' 

But here's the crazy part, the request is still succeeding with a 200 status.  It doesn't get caught at the server level and I'm not noticing any Access-Control-Allow-Origin response headers.  I'm using Fetch to make the requests in the React front end.
UPDATE: It appears that that the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is actually being generated on a successful policy.  I added this custom header in Chrome Dev Tools and saw it populated on success but empty on cors policy failure.  So that part seems to be working correctly.
What I was expecting to happen is to see some browser message that the  request failed due to Cors or that ASP.NET Core would disallow the request.
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using NLog;
using NLog.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);//WebApplicationBuilder
var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Debug("init main");
builder.Logging.AddNLogWeb("nlog.config");
builder.Host.UseNLog();

 builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(o=>o.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44497")
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .WithExposedHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"));
});
builder.Services.AddControllers();
var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
   app.UseHsts();
   app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
} else {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
 
app.UseHttpsRedirection();   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions 
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(app.Environment.ContentRootPath,"ClientApp")),
        RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
    
});

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
//app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
app.Run();


Please share your Program.cs file and let us check the CORS setting.

From the error message, the port is https://localhost:44498, and in your cors setting, you are allowing 44497. Please check it and tell us if it is the root cause.

That’s the point I’m trying to simiulate a situation where the request would be blocked but it’s still going through with a 200 status. All I get is a log message in the request pipeline no browser message that request is blocked.

Hello Charles, for untrusted Origin, custom middleware is needed to intercept requests that fail to execute the CORS policy. Because the CORS phenomenon is the behavior of the browser, and the return of 200 is returned after the server processes it, adding custom middleware to return, for example, a status code of 407 (or other) can solve this issue.

I was looking at that but it's not actually generating an error, just a log message from the CorsService.

Hi Charles, could you kindly use AddPolicy for checking ? I am guessing this question is related to AddDefaultPolicy. I will check the issue when I am free tomorrow.
